# Problem installing MonoDevelop 2.10.5 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, monodevelop

These are the steps I'm doing

```
> git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
Cloning into monodevelop...
remote: Counting objects: 252453, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (47535/47535), done.
remote: Total 252453 (delta 204992), reused 250817 (delta 203552)
Receiving objects: 100% (252453/252453), 109.36 MiB | 226 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (204992/204992), done.
```

Then I do, (is this step correct?)

```
> sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop
[sudo] password for tarun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I then do

```
> cd monodevelop
> ./configure
The build profile 'default' does not exist. A new profile will be created.
Select the packages to include in the build for the profile 'default':

1. [X] main
2. [ ] extras/JavaBinding
3. [ ] extras/ValaBinding
4. [ ] extras/MonoDevelop.Database
5. [ ] extras/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb
6. [ ] extras/PyBinding
7. [ ] extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac
8. [ ] extras/MonoDevelop.MeeGo

Enter the number of an add-in to enable/disable,
(q) quit, (c) clear all, (s) select all, or ENTER to continue:  s

Select the packages to include in the build for the profile 'default':

1. [X] main
2. [X] extras/JavaBinding
3. [X] extras/ValaBinding
4. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.Database
5. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb
6. [X] extras/PyBinding
7. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac
8. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.MeeGo

Enter the number of an add-in to enable/disable,
(q) quit, (c) clear all, (s) select all, or ENTER to continue:  

Configuring package: main
-------------------------
Configuration options: 
Running aclocal  ...
Running automake --foreign  ...
configure.in:3: installing `./install-sh'
configure.in:3: installing `./missing'
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-compile-warnings --prefix=/usr/local ...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for gmcs... /usr/bin/gmcs
checking for update-mime-database... /usr/bin/update-mime-database
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for UNMANAGED_DEPENDENCIES_MONO... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/bin/dmcs
checking for MONO_ADDINS... yes
checking for MONO_ADDINS_SETUP... yes
checking for MONO_ADDINS_GUI... yes
checking for GLIB_SHARP... yes
checking for GTK_SHARP... yes
checking for GLADE_SHARP... yes
checking for MONODOC... yes
checking for GNOME_SHARP... yes
checking for GNOME_VFS_SHARP... yes
checking for GCONF_SHARP... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating build/Makefile
config.status: creating build/MacOSX/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/Mono.Cecil/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/NRefactory/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/Sharpen/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/NGit/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/NSch/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Mono.Debugging/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/BuildVariables.cs
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/MacCrashLogger/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdcrashlog/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdhost/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdtool/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/SharpCoco/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdmonitor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDeveloperExtensions/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDeveloperExtensions/NUnit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/NUnit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/NUnit/NUnitRunner/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/Autotools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/ILAsmBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VBNetBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/prj2make-sharp-lib/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/ChangeLogAddIn/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libsteticui/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Mono.TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/TextTransform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Autotools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Gettext/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/GnomePlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MacPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Moonlight/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.XmlEditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.CodeMetrics/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Refactoring/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugging.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.Moonlight/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.HexEditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.DocFood/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/UnitTests/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating monodevelop
config.status: creating mdtool
config.status: creating monodevelop.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop-core-addins.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop-core-mac-addins.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop.spec
config.status: creating po/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating theme-icons/Makefile
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings

Configuration summary

   * Installation prefix = /usr/local
   * C# compiler = /usr/bin/dmcs
   * Mono class library development extensions: yes
       * Version control providers:
   *     Subversion (Unix): yes
   *     Git: yes
   * Platform bindings: GNOME 
   * Unit tests: no

Now type `make' to compile MonoDevelop
Configuring package: extras/JavaBinding
---------------------------------------
Configuration options: 
Looking for required packages
Checking for package 'mono-addins'.. found.
Checking for package 'gtk-sharp-2.0'.. found.
Checking for package 'glade-sharp-2.0'.. found.
Checking for package 'monodevelop'.. found.

monodevelop-java has been configured with 
        prefix = /usr/local
        config = DEBUG

Configuring package: extras/ValaBinding
---------------------------------------
Configuration options: 
Running aclocal  ...
Running automake --gnu  ...
configure.in:3: installing `./install-sh'
configure.in:3: installing `./missing'
Makefile.am: installing `./INSTALL'
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-compile-warnings --prefix=/usr/local ...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/bin/dmcs
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for UNMANAGED_DEPENDENCIES_MONO... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/bin/dmcs
checking for MONO_ADDINS... yes
checking for MONO_ADDINS_SETUP... yes
checking for MONO_ADDINS_GUI... yes
checking for GLIB_SHARP... yes
checking for GTK_SHARP... yes
checking for GLADE_SHARP... yes
checking for MONODEVELOP... yes
checking for MONODEVELOP_CORE_ADDINS... yes
checking for GNOME_SHARP... yes
checking for GNOME_VFS_SHARP... yes
checking for GCONF_SHARP... yes
checking for LIBVALA... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libvala-0.12 >= 0.12.0) were not met:

No package 'libvala-0.12' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBVALA_CFLAGS
and LIBVALA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I'm following [this tutorial](http://chornsokun.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/build-monodevelop-on-ubuntu-11-10/#comment-523)

But, I have no clue what this means :

```
>sudo make && make run
```

What am I supposed to do next?

***UPDATE***

I installed `libvala-0.12-dev`, and re-ran `./configure`, it worked well, I then did

```
> sudo make && make run
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(41,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(37,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacInterop' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(40,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(41,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(42,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(46,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IXcodeTrackedProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(46,84): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `INativeReferencingProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(103,52): error CS0118: `MonoDevelop.MonoMac.MonoMacProject.IXcodeTrackedProject.XcodeProjectTracker' is a `property' but a `type' was expected
MonoMacCommands.cs(34,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacPackagingTool.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProjectMigrationHandler.cs(37,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(155,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PlistDictionary' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(155,80): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PlistObjectBase' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(219,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FilePair' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(231,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FilePair' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(289,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FilePair' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(53,96): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ApplicationStartInfo' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(180,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProcessSerialNumber' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(184,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProcessSerialNumber' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(77,17): error CS0118: `MonoDevelop.MonoMac.MonoMacProject.IXcodeTrackedProject.XcodeProjectTracker' is a `property' but a `type' was expected
MonoMacProject.cs(79,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IXcodeTrackedProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(105,44): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacProject.cs(113,53): error CS0115: `MonoDevelop.MonoMac.MonoMacProject.MonoMacXcodeProjectTracker.GetFrameworks()' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
MonoMacProject.cs(118,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `XcodeProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
gtk-gui/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.Gui.MonoMacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(15,45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
gtk-gui/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.Gui.MonoMacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(31,45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Gui/MacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(28,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Gui/MacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacInterop' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Gui/MacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(134,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SigningIdentityCombo' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
MonoMacPackaging.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacPackaging.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
MonoMacPackaging.cs(40,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacInterop' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
            Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
            Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.csproj".-- FAILED
        Done building project "/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.csproj".-- FAILED
    Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "Build" in project "/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.sln".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.

Warnings:

/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->

    /usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'MonoMac, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' not resolved
    /usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'MonoDevelop.MacDev, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' not resolved
    /usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'MacPlatform, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' not resolved

Errors:

/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(41,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(37,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacInterop' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(40,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(41,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(42,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(46,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IXcodeTrackedProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(46,84): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `INativeReferencingProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(103,52): error CS0118: `MonoDevelop.MonoMac.MonoMacProject.IXcodeTrackedProject.XcodeProjectTracker' is a `property' but a `type' was expected
    MonoMacCommands.cs(34,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacPackagingTool.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProjectMigrationHandler.cs(37,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(155,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PlistDictionary' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(155,80): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PlistObjectBase' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(219,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FilePair' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(231,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FilePair' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacBuildExtension.cs(289,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FilePair' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(53,96): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ApplicationStartInfo' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(180,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProcessSerialNumber' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacExecutionHandler.cs(184,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProcessSerialNumber' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(77,17): error CS0118: `MonoDevelop.MonoMac.MonoMacProject.IXcodeTrackedProject.XcodeProjectTracker' is a `property' but a `type' was expected
    MonoMacProject.cs(79,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IXcodeTrackedProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(105,44): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacProject.cs(113,53): error CS0115: `MonoDevelop.MonoMac.MonoMacProject.MonoMacXcodeProjectTracker.GetFrameworks()' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
    MonoMacProject.cs(118,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `XcodeProject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    gtk-gui/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.Gui.MonoMacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(15,45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    gtk-gui/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.Gui.MonoMacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(31,45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Gui/MacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(28,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Gui/MacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacInterop' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Gui/MacPackagingSettingsWidget.cs(134,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SigningIdentityCombo' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    MonoMacPackaging.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacPackaging.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacDev' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    MonoMacPackaging.cs(40,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `MacInterop' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

     3 Warning(s)
     34 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.6804350
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tarun/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac'
```

What do I do about the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [libvala-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libvala-dev) [image: Install libvala-dev]
 is missing, i would start with `sudo apt-get install libvala-dev` and then re-run `./configure.`

If the config scripts runs without problems, you can start building monodevelop using `sudo make && make run`.

The [control operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) `&&` in the last line tells that the second command (`make run`) should get executed only if the first command (`sudo make`) runs without problems. It's a way to chain multiple commands together while considering that the latter command should run only if the former command finished without errors.

**EDIT:**

I assume the errors are caused by the MonoMac Extra package that you've selected when running `./configure` the first time:

```
7. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac
```

I'm not sure whether this extra module can be build on a Linux system. If you don't want to create Mac OSX or MeeGo Applications, i would recommend to deactivate those extra packages.

I assume you will have to run `./configure --select` instead of simply `./configure` to modify your initial selection.

**EDIT 2:**

Running Monodevelop using `make run` will work, but the running version isn't "installed" system-wide. This is useful if you want to test different MonoDevelop versions without installing and deinstalling them. If you want to use the compiled version as default version, i think it's recommended to install it first.

To do so, first check the `--prefix` option of the `configure` script. It determines the base directory where to install the compiled stuff. Usually it points to `/usr/local` or something similar, maybe you want to change it to `/opt/monodevelop` or something like that.

In short:

1. remove old artifacts from prior builds using `sudo make clean` ;
2. re-run configure using `./configure --select --prefix=/opt/monodevelop`
3. Build and install it using `sudo make` and `sudo make install`.

If `sudo make install` was successful, you don't need `make run` anymore, instead you can run the installed MonoDevelop.

To create a starter or shortcut, you could create a file `Monodevelop.desktop` and place it into `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/application` It may have the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=MonoDevelop
GenericName=MonoDevelop IDE
Comment=MonoDevelop IDE
Exec=***path to executable*** - customize
Icon=***path to icon, usually PNG*** - customize
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Development;IDE
```

Then, you can drag it to the start menu or onto your desktop.

See also [this tutorial on building and running MonoDevelop on Ubuntu Linux](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Building_MonoDevelop_on_Ubuntu).

Comment: I've updated my question, please have a look

Comment: done, check please

Comment: @tohywawohu I've updated the errors and warnings only, couldn't upload the entire thing 'coz of character limit

Comment: got some errors for the MeeGo add-in as well, de-selected that in the `./configure` .. WORKING FINE now :) thanks a ton mate !

Comment: Just one last question, as of now, I have to run it from the terminal every time with `make run`, it's not showing up in my list of apps.. How do I do that?

Comment: @Tarun: see edit #2 :-)

Comment: the `icon` value needs to be the `path to the image file?` can it be a `png`, `bmp` file?

And, the value for `EXEC` is the `path` to what exactly?

Comment: @Tarun: Icons are usually PNG files. I'm sure Monodevlop is shipped with some own icons. The exec path depends on your installation, esp. the value of `--prefix` when configuring the source package. Assuming you've used `./configure --select --prefix=/opt/monodevelop`, it would be `/opt/monodevelop/bin/monodevelop`. BTW, i've added a link to another online tutorial on building Monodevelop on Ubuntu.